# React/RCTDefines.h file not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, react-native, healthkit

I am looking to add the Apple Health-Kit to my React-Native project. After following the instructions here:  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-apple-healthkit)

the build fails and the following error appears.

[image: XCode Build Error]

I am not sure why this error is occurring or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

go to the file and replace this line where the error occurs

```
#import <React/RCTDefines.h>
```

with this line

```
#import "RCTDefines.h"
```

Comment: I cant find the file with that import command. The files that are linked to that error do not have that first import command.

Comment: just double clicking the error ( line in red color) xcode will take you to that file.

Comment: Double clicking this line does not take me to the file. I have gone down through the files in my file explorer on the left and cant find a file with #import <React/RCTDefines.h> in it

Answer (score 0):

The three files linked do not include the line

```
#import <React/RCTDefines.h>
```

Here is what appears in the files linked.

[image]

[image]

[image]